# Python requests session: auth not passed to requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to retrive data from a mobile game to post updates via discord bot. There is no problem to get those data from unlinked account.
But if login is via google play it makes autentitication first with long id token, which also sucseed and short token is obtained, but when i'm making next request with short token i get {"detail":"Invalid token."}. in https tooklit traffic there no other steps between, so looks like autorisation is not passed somehow to the secon request.
Any tips for beginer?

```py
session=requests.Session()

URL0 = "https://URL/auth-login-google/"
headers0={
    'accept':'application/json',
    'accept-encoding':'gzip',
    'content-length':'1137',
    'content-type':'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'host':'api.lost-vault.com',
    'user-agent':'Dart/3.0 (dart:io)'
}
body0={
  "id_token": "LONG_ID_TOKEN",  
  "platform": "android"
}

post0=session.post(URL0, headers=headers0, json=body0)


URL = "https://URL"
headers={
    'accept':'application/json',
    'accept-encoding':'gzip',
    'authorization':'Token SHORT_TOKEN',
    'host':'api.lost-vault.com',
    'user-agent':'Dart/3.0 (dart:io)'
}

r=session.get(URL, headers=headers)
```

Post Request:
[image: POST REQUEST]
Response Body:
[image: POST RESPONSE BODY]
Get Request
[image: GET REQUEST]

Comment: Are you sure that the format of the request is an `Authorization` header, with value "Token SHORT_TOKEN"? And is the token passed to the web request valid?

Comment: This is the only info sent according to traffic analysis...

Comment: So, are you sure the "SHORT_TOKEN" you sent is a valid one?

Comment: Yes, I copied it from first post request and on top it is always same token, that doesn't change across devices. For a character without google login this short token works without problems so no need to use Session, but here seems there is some trick.
I also tried to put long token in second get request 'authorization' and body, but no luck

Comment: If all headers are the exact same then there should be no reason for different results. Can you double check, maybe the other headers or the URL is wrong?

Comment: Checked out again, all fits. So the code seems to be right and work in same session?
I'll try to figure out later what can cause the issue then

Comment: Yes. Just by looking at your code, everything seems correct. If possible can you share the traffic analysis to further debug the issue? You can blur out the sensitive information.

Comment: Hello, I added screenshots of traffic

Comment: You seem to miss the device-id game-version and game-language headers. Have you tried adding them?

Comment: Now I feel really dumb, that worked thanks! Really huge Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As David said, I missed few arguments in my header, now it works like a charm!